# coreplot: reloadDataInIndexRange -- how to use it?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

currently, I am using CPTXYGraph to plot my x,y graphs on my iphone application. However, I feel that the reloadData function is especially costly when I need the data to plot dynamically in real time. I would like to use reloadDataInIndexRange function... but I can't seem to access it.

Any ideas on how to access this function?

Answer (score 1):

Call it on the plot like you would any other method:

```
[plot reloadDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(location, length)];
```